# Downloaded file is not showing in iPhone from ionic app using `cordova file transfer plugin`

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, file-transfer

I am using cordova-plugin-file-transfer in my ionic 3 app to download the file from url in ios devices. The file is downloaded successfully. But I am not able to see downloaded file on ios device.

**Here is my code:**

```
const transfer = this.transfer.create();
        transfer.download(url, cordova.file.documentsDirectory + fileName).then(
                  entry => {
                    console.log(entry);
                    console.log("Download Succeeded.");
                  },
                  error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log("Download Failed.");
                  }
                )
```

Where my downloaded file is stored and how I can access my downloaded files in ios devices?

When we download an image from WhatsApp it will be stored and shown in photos app. How does the same work for my ionic app?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

```
import { normalizeURL} from ‘ionic-angular’; 

const transfer = this.transfer.create();
            transfer.download(encodeURI(url), normalizeURL(cordova.file.documentsDirectory + fileName)).then(
                      entry => {
                        console.log(entry);
                        console.log("Download Succeeded.");
                      },
                      error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        console.log("Download Failed.");
                      }
                    )
```

Comment: you can use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/photo-library If the file is an image and if you would like to show it in a phone image gallery.